# Only one value from an hidden input is being displayed

Tags: php, javascript, forms

```
<?php
foreach($_color_swatch as $_inner_option_id){
  preg_match_all('/((#?[A-Za-z0-9]+))/', $_option_vals[$_inner_option_id]['internal_label'], $matches);
  if ( count($matches[0]) > 0 ) {
    $color_value = $matches[1][count($matches[0])-1];
?>

<li>
<input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="<?php echo $color_value;?>"/>
<div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolor').value);">
 <img src="<?php echo $color_value;?>.png" /></div>
</li>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

This works for displaying the images, using the $color_value but i need to pass the value from hidden input to another javascript function.
And when i click on div it displays only one value no matter how many are inside the foreach.
Can anyone give me a little help? Thanks.

This is the output:

```
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="red"/>
    <div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolor').value);"><img src="red.png"/></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="blue"/>
    <div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolor').value);"><img src="blue.png"/></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="white"/>
    <div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolor').value);"><img src="white.png"/></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="green"/>
    <div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolorx').value);"><img src="green.png"/></div>
    </li>
```

But when i click on each of the divs, it displays only the value of the second, blue.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML and JavaScript look like when there are multiple items?

Comment: try diffrent ids for each hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    <?php
    $cont = 0;

    foreach($_color_swatch as $_inner_option_id){
      preg_match_all('/((#?[A-Za-z0-9]+))/', $_option_vals[$_inner_option_id]['internal_label'], $matches);
      if ( count($matches[0]) > 0 ) {
        $color_value = $matches[1][count($matches[0])-1];
    ?>

    <li>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor<?php echo $cont; ?>" value="<?php echo $color_value;?>"/>
    <div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakecolor<?php echo $cont; ?>').value);">
     <img src="<?php echo $color_value;?>.png" /></div>
    </li>

    <?php
    }
    $cont = $cont + 1;
    }
    ?>
```

In this way every input hidden have a different id, the same whit the onclick function.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thanks, that worked but how i get that value like this:<script type="text/javascript">
 function somefunction(element, optionTitle) {
  var num = document.getElementById('fakecolor').value;</script>  Ignore the syntax here, i want to get that value :)

Comment: If you click on the divs it's suposed to alert the value of every input hidden...now you want another function...in a button or something??....explain me to make it one ;)

Comment: <?php $i=0;?>
<?php foreach($x as $y): ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="fakecolor<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $someVariable;?>"/>
<?php $cont = $cont + 1; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?> 

I want to get the value of each fakecolor like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
function somefunction(element, optionTitle) {
var num = document.getElementById('fakecolor').value;
...
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand what you're trying to do, still:

```
<input type="hidden" id="fakecolor" value="<?php echo $color_value;?>"/>
<div onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fakevalue').value);">
```

First line: you're using an unique id while looping so you'll get several elements with the same id and you'll always end up with the first one with document.getElementById.
Second line: aren't you supposed to get the value of the hidden field ? (ie #fakecolor and not #fakevalue as you're getting).

Comment: You've still got several times the same id. Just add something to the id (like **id="fakecolor_$i"** where $i would be increased each time you pass through the loop) so you can make the difference and get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple IDs on the same page which will cause `getElementById` to fail. Why don't you loop and construct your JavaScript like so:

```
<div onclick="alert("<?php echo $color_value; ?>");">
```

If you ever move from just `alert` you can have whatever JavaScript function with a string parameter to accept the color value.